# Call a method in a class without a main method

Tags: java

I have a class but it doesn't have main and I can't execute it. Should I make another class with main to execute my small project or should I add main here. How can I call this method in main class?

This is my class.

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Cycle
{

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     int gjeresia_e_kornizes = 300;
     int gjatesia_e_kornizes = 200;
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.fillRect(0,0,gjeresia_e_kornizes, gjatesia_e_kornizes);
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     int skaji_majtas = 105;
     int lart =70;
     int gjeresia = 90;
     int lartesia = 60;
     g.drawRect(skaji_majtas, lart, gjeresia, lartesia);
     int diametri = 40;
     g.fillOval(skaji_majtas+gjeresia-diametri,lart, diametri, diametri);

  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you may have just searched "how to draw graphics in Java", and copied the code for it. Unfortunately, it's not quite as simple (although not too much harder) than just having a `paintComponent` method. I'd suggest looking up a basic tutorial on Swing.

Comment: When you add the main method, you may notice nothing is getting drawn (if you have no other code outside this). The reason for this is because `paintComponent(Graphics g)` should be overridden from another class, some type of `JComponent` such as a `JPanel`. If you know about things such as inheritence and overriding I would recommend you do a google search for how to draw to a JPanel. If you do not, I would recommend starting [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html), or one of the other links provided in the answers, and going some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Look here for a [basic tutorial for Swing](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/). You now alter your class to extend JPanel.

```
public class Cycle extends JPanel
{

  @Override   // just to make sure we really override this
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     int gjeresia_e_kornizes = 300;
     int gjatesia_e_kornizes = 200;
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.fillRect(0,0,gjeresia_e_kornizes, gjatesia_e_kornizes);
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     int skaji_majtas = 105;
     int lart =70;
     int gjeresia = 90;
     int lartesia = 60;
     g.drawRect(skaji_majtas, lart, gjeresia, lartesia);
     int diametri = 40;
     g.fillOval(skaji_majtas+gjeresia-diametri,lart, diametri, diametri);

  }
}
```

In the code from the tutorial, instead of adding all the components, you add your Cycle. Done. I think you will need to set the size of your Cycle. (Note: I didn't test this)

Answer (score 0):

Either way is possible. You can add `main` method to this class or write a driver class. Having a driver class is helpful, if you have bigger code-base.

Answer (score 0):

You can add main method in this class or in another class. In order to execute it, you need to create an instance of Cycle and invoke this method.

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Cycle
{

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
 int gjeresia_e_kornizes = 300;
 int gjatesia_e_kornizes = 200;
 g.setColor(Color.red);
 g.fillRect(0,0,gjeresia_e_kornizes, gjatesia_e_kornizes);
 g.setColor(Color.red);
 int skaji_majtas = 105;
 int lart =70;
 int gjeresia = 90;
 int lartesia = 60;
 g.drawRect(skaji_majtas, lart, gjeresia, lartesia);
 int diametri = 40;
 g.fillOval(skaji_majtas+gjeresia-diametri,lart, diametri, diametri);
 }

public static void main (

//instanciate a new Cycle object
Cycle cycle = new Cycle();
cycle.paintComponent(g);// g is the Graphics reference
}

}
```

One more thing is if you have to extend `Jpanel`, you can override using @override this method as well. Simply, Graphics g is actually a property of the Super class. The method call happens in the higher level in the class hierarchy

Comment: it said to me that g cannot be resolved to a variable...What can I do

Comment: Check this link -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

Answer (score 0):

Either way will be fine. If you have a big enough project, create a separate driver class that does the configuration and setup for you in addition to having a main() method. On the other hand, for a small project it is often better to put the main method into one of the class files.

Answer (score 0):

Either ought to work.  Whichever is better might depend on how large your project is and what you are doing with it.  Is your project just the one class?  If so, I would add the main method to that class, create a Cycle object, and call paintComponent() on it.  If it is part of a larger system, it would be better to have a specific main class for the system that starts the application, which will call Cycle when and how it is needed.